# Kendo UI Grid resizable bug

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem with `Kendo UI Grid`. When I make grid resizable and I set width of each columns, the cursor that resize it is misaligned.

There is a simple example:

[JSFiddle1](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr1nk9bp/) or [JsFiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr1nk9bp/)

```
$("#uxUsersToTransfer").kendoGrid({
    height: 100,
    resizable: true,
    columns: [ ... ],
});
```

UPDATE WITH SOLUTION:

This is a possible resolution: [JsFiddle3](http://jsfiddle.net/xwsa7oom/) You can just remove final column's width to make it works !

Comment: @Ajay2707: hi, inline code spans (`like this`) aren't meant to be used for highlighting text, only for code. See [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990) for more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the kendo [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/appearance#column-widths) you either need to enable horizontal scrolling, change the widths to percentages, or leave one column without a width property.

> If all columns have pixel widths and their sum exceeds the width of the grid, a horizontal scrollbar will appear (if scrolling is enabled). If that sum is less than the width of the grid, the column widths will be ignored and all columns will expand. This will lead to undesired side effects, e.g. when resizing columns. In old IE versions the column widths will be obeyed, but misalignment will occur. That's why it is recommended to have at least one column without specified width, so that it can adjust freely. Explicit widths for all columns should be set only if they are set in percent, or if their sum exceeds the Grid width and the goal is to have horizontal scrolling.